Cant Download PDF file when Hosting
currently i develop website by using flutter , there are button for download the PDF , when in debug mode by using command flutter run -d chrome i can download the PDF, but after i host and try it, it wont even download.
Here is the button code
DataCell(
                        Center(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 150,
                              height: 35,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  try {
                                    await QuotationPDF.generatePDF(quotation);
                                  } catch (error) {
                                    print('Error generating PDF: $error');
                                  }
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  'Download',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

i expect it can download when i deploy hosting instead of only can download when in debug mode.
